# Legendum excolit mundum

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I am trying to translate "Reading improves the world" to Latin.
My translation is:

> Legendum excolit mundum.

Is this a good translation?
I can't understand if I should use *legendum* or *legere*.

Perhaps, *Mundus legendo excoletur* can better express the meaning I want to convey. “The world (people / nations) will be improved by reading".

Comment: Ok. Joonas, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choice of words is good: *mundus* for "world", *excolere* for "improve", *legere* for "read".
I would go with the passive and express the means by a gerund ablative.
Thus my suggestion is: ***mundus excolitur legendo***.

The word order is quite flexible, so any of the six possible orders works.
Your suggestion *mundus legendo excoletur* works, too.
You have used the future tense instead of the present, and that is fine if you want to stress that the improvement will happen in the future.
I chose the present tense to make it a general rule without discussing whether the reading and improving are actually happening now.